# Why This NASM Assembly is Not Printing?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to learn NASM Assembly (on Linux, so AT&T syntax), but I am stuck trying to print "Hello World" via syscall. The code below assembles and runs fine, but it doesn't print anything. Any clues why?

```
.text
.globl main

main:
        movl $4, %eax
        movl $1, %ebx
        movl string1, %ecx
        movl $20, %edx
        int $0x80

.data
string1: .string "hello world"
```

**UPDATE**: I found it. I need to include a $ symbol in front of the "string1", so the line becomes "movl $string1, %ecx". Any explanation of what happens when I don't include it though?

Comment: Just for clarity, this is not Nasm. It's "AT&T syntax". Gas uses it, and Yasm will accept it as an alternative, but not Nasm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syscall you're using expects a pointer to the string in `ecx`.  That's what adding the `$` does - puts the *value* of `string1` into `ecx`.  If you leave the `$` off, you're putting the first word located at `string1` into `ecx` - whatever the equivalent numeric value of `hell` happens to be.  On a little-endian machine with an ASCII string (which should be your case), that means you're putting `0x6c6c6568` into `ecx`.  It's not likely that that value is a valid pointer to a string of any kind, so the syscall happens to not print anything.  It could just as easily have crashed or caused some other kind of crazy behaviour.